# minted custom numbering

Tags: minted

Is it possible to define custom numbers to each source code line, like:

```
1 string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
22 /*
23 Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
24 of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
25 circle of diameter $d$.
26 */
30-40 ...
162 const double pi = 3.1415926535
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to do this.  But if you work with `fancyvrb`, which is what `minted` uses internally, you can probably figure out a way to do this.  You would want to look at the counter `FancyVerbLine` (line number) and maybe the macro `\theFancyVerbLine` (typesetting style).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice workaround is the use of minted's texcomments option:

```
\inputminted[texcomments]{python}{code/excerpt.py}
```

In your code, just add a comment:

```
# \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{20}
```

Comment: A nice workaround!